# How to maintain the size of a ListView when used within a UserControl and parent WindowDialog

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, user-controls

I've been fighting this xaml for hours now. It should be very simple. I have a general **WindowDialog** (Billing.WindowDialog) with a **ContentPresenter** displaying a UserControl (NovaLibraries.Views.DxLibraryView). The **UserControl** itself has a **ListView** (in row=0) and followed by other controls in the below rows.

The good news: When the WindowDialog presents the UserControl, it correctly displays the UserControl to the size of the display screen and minimizing the
WindowDialog (or resizing it) does correctly change the size of the UserControl and shrinks the ListView correctly.

The problem (the bad news): When a filter is placed on the list contained within the ListView, so that the ListView has fewer items, it shrinks due to lack of items and the entire UserControl shrinks. This becomes very distracting when the list is large with a hundred items then shrinks to 4 items as this causes the entire UserControl to shrink in size.

What I Need: **I need the UserControl initially to be maximized to the size of the screen with the ListView using all available space. The UserControl is to shrink (or enlarge) according to its parent WindowDialog--not according to the contents of the ListView.**

Thanks for reading all this. Any help is most appreciated.

The WindowDialog:

```
<Window x:Class="Billing.WindowDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        Title="{Binding DialogTitle}">

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="DialogPresenter" Content="{Binding .}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Window>


using System.Windows;
using Client;

namespace Billing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WindowDialog.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class WindowDialog : Window, IWindowDialog
    {
        public WindowDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

C# code to dispaly the UserControl:

```
  var dialog = new WindowDialog
   {
        Title = "ICD Library",
        ShowInTaskbar = false,                     
        Topmost = false                            
   };


   DialogService dialogService = new DialogService();
   dialogService.ShowDialog(
               dialog,
               new DxLibraryViewModel(null, null)
               );




// Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed.

        public void ShowDialog<TDialogViewModel>(IWindowDialog windowdialog, TDialogViewModel viewModel, 
            Action<TDialogViewModel> onDialogClose, bool sizetocontent = false)
        {
            // Assign the viewmodel as the DataContext of the WindowDialog.xaml
            windowdialog.DataContext = viewModel;

            // Set window size.
            SizeToContent SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
            WindowState WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            if (sizetocontent)
            {
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
            // The WindowDialog is the mainwindow.
            (windowdialog as WindowDialog).WindowState = WindowState;
            (windowdialog as WindowDialog).SizeToContent = SizeToContent;



            // Open MainWindow in modal fashion (Returns only when the newly opened window is closed).
            // Implicict DataTemplate in App.XAML used to display usercontrol.
            windowdialog.ShowDialog();
        }

        public void ShowDialog<TDialogViewModel>(IWindowDialog mainwindow, TDialogViewModel viewModel, bool sizetocontent = false)
        {
            ShowDialog(mainwindow, viewModel, null, sizetocontent);
        }
```

The UserControl is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NovaLibraries.Views.DxLibraryView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:NovaLibraries.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Background="Beige" >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!--Display a checkmark without the surrounding box as an image-->
        <c:CheckMarkConverter x:Key="mycheckmark" />

        <Style x:Key="ItemContStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Resources>
              <!--ORANGE-->
                <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="OrangeBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1" >
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="#AA00CC00" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.8" Color="Orange" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Style.Resources>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=chronic}"  Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OrangeBrush}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="275" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0" 
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContStyle}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DxView.View}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
                  IsEnabled="{Binding CanSelect}"  
                  Width="781" >

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=rank}"    Header="Rank" Width="50" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=code}"     Header="ICD-9"      Width="50" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=cdesc}"    Header="Diagnosis"  Width="550" />

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Why you are using `ContentPresenter` ? And not doing it like this : `<ContentControl>
            <uc:UserControl2 x:Name="UC1"/>
        </ContentControl>` ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan The WindowDialog is called by a generic ShowDialog to host the ViewModel. Changing ContentPresenter to <ContentControl> made no difference in the changing size of the hosted usercontrol when the listview contents were changed, which is very annoying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By removing

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
```

from the ContentPresenter, the ListView and its parent UserControl behave as expected.